# Firebird dataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird2.1

I would like to see all of the data with column names in my logfile.

```
 private static void ExecuteSQL()
    {

        string conn = "User ID=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=XX.18.137.XXX:C:/ER.TDB;DataSource==XX.18.137.XXX;Charset=NONE;";

        FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(conn);
         FbDataReader myReader = null;
         string sql = "SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS";

        FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
              //  Log.WriteLog(myReader["rdb$relation_name"].ToString());

            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLog(e.ToString());
        } 
    }
```

Right now it's only showing me the `rdb$relation_name` column.

I want to check the different tables for which I don't have the column's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is iterate over all fields printing their names before iterating the results:

```
private static void ExecuteSQL()
{

    string conn = "User ID=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=XX.18.137.XXX:C:/ER.TDB;DataSource==XX.18.137.XXX;Charset=NONE;";

    FbConnection myConnection = new FbConnection(conn);
     FbDataReader myReader = null;
     string sql = "SELECT * FROM RDB$RELATIONS";

    FbCommand myCommand = new FbCommand(sql, myConnection);
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // 1. print all field names
        for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
          Log.WriteLog(myReader.GetName(i));
        }

        // 2. print each record
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
          // 3. for each record, print every field value
          for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
          {
            Log.WriteLog(myReader[i].ToString());
          }

        }
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteLog(e.ToString());
    } 
}
```

I am pretty sure, that this will give ugly output as it prints every output to a new line. You should be able to change this to print the fields and each record in rows.

Comment: thank you for your help, Its work for me. for one row data its work. for multiple line l changed my writelog method. ALL SET.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<string> GetColumnNames(string queryString)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        List<string> listOfColumns = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(queryString, conn))
                {
                    // Call Read before accessing data.
                    FbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            listOfColumns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            BinwatchLogging.Log(e);
        }

        return listOfColumns;

       // return result;
    }
```

where querystring is your query (eg: select * from yourtablename) and connstring is your firebird connectionstring

Comment: or you can directly execute on dataadapter and fill dataset which will you both columnNames and data